# Facebook Graph API Events ticket_uri not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When fetching a Facebook event from the Facebook Graph API, there is a field for the ticket_uri

The response always looks like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ajax/events/ticket.php?event_id=1461866457391623&source=12&ext=[aBigNumber]&hash=[randomhash]
```

which basically works in the current browser session, but does not work when saved and used somewhere else, like an other browser.

Is there a solution to redirect the user to the correct "Book now" url

Answer (score 0):

That's the intended operation of that field - It's intended to be used by the current session user (i,e whose access token you're using) and contains a user/session specific hash which will expire -

If you want to link arbitrary other users (i.e. who aren't using your app) to the event for ticket purchasing reasons, the only alternative is to link them to the Event on Facebook.com and have them click it themselves